# Printing a Dictionary Value in Jinja

Tags: python, dictionary, flask, jinja2

I'm passing a dictionary to a Jinja template like this:

```
locations = {1: "Baltimore, MD"}
```

I want the value to appear like this:

```
Baltimore, MD
```

But, when I print the value in my Jinja template, it looks like this:

```
{'Baltimore, MD'}
```

Here's my code (in the template):

```
<td class="col-md-2">{{ locations[check.location_id] | string }}</td>
```

I tried adding a `[0]` to the end of `locations[check.location_id]` and it didn't help.

What's wrong?

Comment: Are you **100% certain** that `locations` is not set to `{1: {"Baltimore, MD"}}` instead? In Python 3, that would lead to the same output you see now.

Comment: Yup, I'm **110%** certain. I can't figure out where the extra brackets are coming from.

Comment: @user3689902 I think, this question is ideal for making it full working example.

Comment: So what happens when you use `{{ locations }}` then? Can you show us the output for that?

Comment: In the console, `locations` prints `{1: 'Baltimore, MD'}` but rendered through the Jinja template, `{{ locations }}` prints `{1: {'Baltimore, MD'}}`.

Comment: @user3689902: so what does your template do to make the value a set? Between your `print` and you using the dictionary in your template, the value has been updated to be a set containing the string, not just the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide a full example, as extrapolating from the information given, the code works fine.  Here's an example.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    check = {'location_id': 1}
    locations = {1: "Baltimore, MD"}
    return render_template('example.html', locations=locations, check=check)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Then `example.html`:

```
{{ locations[check.location_id] }}
```

Shows:

```
Baltimore, MD
```

in the rendered template.